# Вложение компонентов во внешний шаблон на vue

Tags: javascript, mvc, vue.js, mvvm, vue-router

Хочу сделать такую структуру приложения на Vue(псевдокод):

```
<app>
<menu></menu>
<layout>
<content></content>
</layout>
</app>
```

`app` - загружается из индекс, смотрит настройки и загружает компонент layout из отдельного файла.

`layout` - по сути просто шаблон.

`content` - также грузится из индекс, отображает состояние роутера.

Как сделать такое? На angular1.6 делал так:

index.html:

```
<html ng-app="app" id="ng-app">
  <head>js,css,meta</head>
  <body>
      <div ng-if="config.layout"
       ng-include="'/layout/' + (config.layout||'default') + '/template.html'">
          загрузка...
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

template.html:

```
<div>
всякая разметка,
<ng-view></ng-view> 
всякая разметка 
</div>
```

Comment: [Распределение контента слотами](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: В песочнице заработало! Оказалось `View` - плохое имя для компонента

Comment: Не совсем понял комментарий про имя компонента :) Если ты решил задачу, добавь свой ответ с описанием того как решал

Comment: По документации копипастил(только начинаю c vue). Крутил-вертел - никак не отображается компонент content. Оказалось от того что я назвал его `View`. Сменил имя - заработала разметка. Вечером ещё роутер запущу тогда можно будет считать вопрос решенным.

Comment: Не забудь ответ добавить, когда все заработает

Answer (score 0):

Получилось загрузить шаблон отдельно от бандла вот таким образом:

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
/* eslint-disable */

Vue.component('Layout', function (resolve, reject) {
  axios.get('static/layout.html').then(function (request) {
    resolve({
      template: request.data
    })
  })
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App><Layout/></App>'
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

static/layout.html

```
<div>
  <img src="./assets/logo.png">
  разметка
    <router-view/>
  разметка
</div>
```

В остальном обычный шаблон `vue-cli webpack`

Comment: странное решение какое-то, а почему надо было _загрузить шаблон отдельно от бандла_?

Comment: Брендирование сервиса.